# Tooltips/Labels in Cisco packet tracer are empty

Tags: networking, ubuntu-mate, cisco

I've installed Packet Tracer 7.0 in Ubuntu Mate 17.04, and the tooltips/labels that appear when you hover the mouse over the devices are empty ( or maybe the text is the same color of the background?). It's just a plain white box.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, and I'm running Ubuntu MATE 16.04. Curiously, the tooltip text is present, yet it's nearly illegible due to it being colored white. I attempted to change the color of the text via Ubuntu MATE's "Appearance Settings" but this had no effect. I checked the Cisco NetAcademy  Bugzilla and it appears that this issue was reported in bug 19971 back on September 16, 2016. After browsing through the comments, I noticed that PacketTracer uses Qt. That led me to my resolution:

1. I closed my PacketTracer (saved my work first, of course) and went to the Menu - Qt 4 Settings. When you click on it, it will open a window called "Qt Settings"
2. On the tab titled "Appearance" I took a look a the "GUI Settings" section.
3. In the "GUI Settings" you will find a pulldown menu. My settings were set to "GTK+"
4. Change the option to "Desktop Settings (Default)"
5. Locate the "File" menu option at the top of the Qt Configuration window, click it, and press "Save"
6. Close the "Qt Settings" window.
7. Open up PacketTracer and check and see if you can see the tooltips. If not, you may need to go back into the Qt 4 Settings and change the colors manually.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much user697536.

This fixed my desktop running MATE 16.04. For my laptop running 17.04 I installed the packages qt4-default and qt4-qtconfig and then followed your instructions, thank you again.